# More than one banner in Notification Center

Tags: macos, notifications

My question is simple, but I think, it's impossible. When more than one banner in Notification Center are rises, previous of them are ends and show last banner only. It would be nice if banners shows as a badges. I think we can't to change this, isn't it?

Comment: If you can snap a picture or mark up a web picture showing notification center, that might help but what I can figure out is you want to redesign the UI for the center entirely.

Comment: It's hard to do, unfortunately. Just imagine - One banner pops up in the top of right corner, using the Notification Center. If another banner pops up from another program or event, the first disappears. So, the second banner does not float below under the first, as a column, and overlaps the first banner. Growl is working as it should, but Notification Center does not, unfortunately. But I think about refusing from Growl, because there are many apps are using NC of OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with the behavior of banners versus alerts.

Banners by design appear for several seconds and then disappear.
Alerts are designed to stay put. You can change the way an application's Notifications behave in the Notifications Preference Pane.

So switch your app's behavior to show alerts instead of banners and you should be fine.

Unless, of course, I'm misunderstanding your question.
[image: Choose alert instead of banners to have the notification stay visible.]

Comment: Actually, I think that the issue is different: as you say, banners disappear after a few seconds. That's fine. But if I have multiple banners, triggered one after the other, I would expect to see all of them appearing, and then disappearing one by one.

What I see is that only one banner at a time is shown (the last one).